# Windows 7 SP1 install fails with code 800F0A09

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I am trying to install SP1 on a Windows 7 Ultimate box using Windows Update, but it fails with this code: 800F0A09 and no further explanation. I have tried to google that, but I am not getting anything useful back. Windows online help is not useful either...

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a  [german blog article](http://www.borncity.com/blog/2011/02/23/windows-7-service-pack-1-troubleshooting-tipps/) it's a problem with Microsoft Security Essentials or Microsoft Forefront Client blocking the installation/deinstallation process. It advises to update those packages. See also [this Microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/why-am-i-receiving-a-message-about-microsoft-security-essentials-or-microsoft-forefront-client-security-when-installing-a-service-pack?71173c08).

Comment: It was forefront, the hotfix linked here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394433/ allowed me to install SP1 fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I accept that the Online Windows Update should work without any problem, but in your case it has not worked. Hope this is not a bug and something to do with Internet download/connection!

I always prefer the Offline Installer, which gives me flexibility to install it at any time or on any number of computers.  Give a try with the Offline Installer:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3202ce6-4056-4059-8a1b-3a9b77cdfdda&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

The hotfix [Forefront Client Security Antimalware Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394433) may not work, depending on your version of  Forefront. You may try uninstalling forefront, installing sp1 via windows update, and re-installing Forefront afterwards. This worked for me, but the above answer did not.